Does async-profiler ctimer profiling mode suffer from the safepoint bias problem?
I am trying to do some CPU profiling against a JVM running inside a container. As I do not manage the cluster I am unable to enable any perf related option or alternative as suggested in the README
So I have been using the -e ctimer option instead of the -e cpu one, but I am wondering if the ctimer option suffers from the Safepoint bias problem.
The only drawback I can read about it in the README is that there will be no kernel stack traces, but I am OK with that.
Are there any other differences I should be aware of?
